# C#: Change List<PictureBox> into an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, picturebox

I'm re-creating Space Invaders for a project of mine, and have used a List for all my invaders and other things, but I need to use an array instead. How can I change this list into an array, I'm not familiar with them. See code below.

```
List<PictureBox> listInvaders;

public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InvaderAnim.Start();

        listInvaders = new List<PictureBox> {invader1, invader2, invader3, invader4, etc};
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: `listInvaders.ToArray()` is the answer and -1 for lack of research.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x303t819.aspx) method defined in System.Collections.Generic namespace:

```
InitializeComponent();
InvaderAnim.Start();

listInvaders = new List<PictureBox> {invader1, invader2, invader3, invader4, etc};
var resultingArray = listInvaders.ToArray();
```

Also you can use the [array initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573.aspx), like this:

```
var resultingArray = new PictureBox[] { invader1, invader2, invader3, invader4, etc }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the compiler resolution of the type will infer the array type.

```
var listInvaders = new[] {invader1, invader2, invader3, invader4, etc};
```

Otherwise, use ToArray() to convert a pre-existing list to an array of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change this list into an array

How about

```
var result = listInvaders.ToArray();
```

Why not create array in the first place instead of List. Will save memory and time

```
var result = new PictureBox[] {invader1, invader2, invader3, invader4, etc};
```